# Repeated 'Too many certificates already issued for exact set of domains' error with GreenLock package

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, lets-encrypt, greenlock

I have already checked [this post](https://git.rootprojects.org/root/greenlock.js/issues/22). But even though I tried that method, it didn't work, so I open a new issue.

I use AWS EC2 server and deploy with aws pipeline. So When I push to github repository, it will automatically build and deploy to production server.

At first it's works fine, and there are no errors in the console.

But one day an error began to occur. So when I checked the console, there was an error as below.

**[Error Message in console]**

```
set greenlockOptions.notify to override the default logger
certificate_order (more info available: account subject altnames challengeTypes)
Error cert_issue:
[acme-v2.js] authorizations were not fetched for 'mydomain.com':
{"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:rateLimited","detail":"Error creating new order :: too many certificates already issued for exact set of domains: mydomain.com: see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/","status":429,"_identifiers":[{"type":"dns","value":"mydomain.com"}]}
Error: [acme-v2.js] authorizations were not fetched for 'mydomain.com':
{"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:rateLimited","detail":"Error creating new order :: too many certificates already issued for exact set of domains: mydomain.com: see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/","status":429,"_identifiers":[{"type":"dns","value":"mydomain.com"}]}
    at Object.E.NO_AUTHORIZATIONS (/home/project/build/node_modules/@root/acme/errors.js:75:9)
    at /home/project/build/node_modules/@root/acme/acme.js:1198:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
Error cert_issue:
[acme-v2.js] authorizations were not fetched for 'mydomain.com':
```

In my opinion, I think there was a limit to the process of reissuing the certificate every time I push the code, but I don't know where the problem occurred even if I check the code.

My code structure is written as below and developed with Express.

**[server.js]**

```
"use strict";

const app = require("./app.js");

require("greenlock-express")
    .init({
        packageRoot: __dirname,
        configDir: "./greenlock.d",

        // contact for security and critical bug notices
        maintainerEmail: process.env.EMAIL,

        // whether or not to run at cloudscale
        cluster: false
    })
    // Serves on 80 and 443
    // Get's SSL certificates magically!
    .serve(app);
```

**[greenlock.d/config.json]**

```
{ "sites": [{ "subject": "mydomain.com", "altnames": ["mydomain.com"] }] }
```

**[.greenlockrc]**

```
{"configDir":"./greenlock.d"}
```

**[package.json (scripts.start line)]**

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

I am aware of the seven-day limit from Let's Encrypt. So I want to find a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my express folder, I do

```
sudo chmod 775 ./greenlock.d
```

then I delete greenlock.d(one time) and npm start

I dont have issue since